nginx configuration for subdirectory based php websites on different php-fpm pool
I'm trying to configure my nginx server to host two php websites (with their respective php-fpm pool) on the same domain:

one on the /
and one in the /nextcloud/ subfolder

I want that each website fallback to their respective base directory index.php if it's requested an uri that is not an actual file:

GET / is served by /var/www/my.domain.net/public/index.php
GET /img/logo.png (an actual file) is served by /var/www/my.domain.net/public/img/logo.png
GET /home.php (an actual file) is served by /var/www/my.domain.net/public/home.php
GET /img/default.png (not an actual file) is served by /var/www/my.domain.net/public/index.php
GET /nextcloud/ is served by /var/www/nextcloud/public/index.php
GET /nextcloud/index.html (an actual file) is served by /var/www/nextcloud/public/index.html
GET /nextcloud/version.php (an actual file) is served by /var/www/nextcloud/public/version.php
GET /nextcloud/user/profile (not an actual file) is served by /var/www/nextcloud/public/index.php

Following countless suggestions on internet I tried different configuration but none worked.
This is the last one I came up with:
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my.domain.net;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/my_domain_net.access.log main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/my_domain_net.error.log;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    root   /var/www/my.domain.net/public;

    location = / {
        #index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location / {
        #root   /var/www/my.domain.net/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri$is_args$args;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
        location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
            #root   /var/www/my.domain.net/public;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/phpfpm-mysite.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location = /nextcloud/ {
        alias     /var/www/nextcloud/public;
        #index     /index.php;
    }

    location /nextcloud/ {
        alias     /var/www/nextcloud/public/;

        location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
            alias   /var/www/nextcloud/public;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^/nextcloud/(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/phpfpm-nextcloud.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri$is_args$args;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

Any suggestion on how make it work as wanted?
After it works I'll have to add the https part. I hope it won't be another blood bath :/
Thanks in advance for your answers

This should work.
server {
    ...

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    root   /var/www/my.domain.net/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/phpfpm-mysite.sock;
            ...
        }
    }

    location /nextcloud/ {
        alias     /var/www/nextcloud/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^/nextcloud/(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/phpfpm-nextcloud.sock;
            ...
        }

    }

    ...
}

PS. I don't get, why would one use fastcgi_split_path_info. You could just pass $request_uri to PATH_INFO.

It doesn't work (isn't it basically the same I posted above? anyway) asking for http://my.domain.net/nextcloud/ I get the answer from the base domain instead of nextcloud...
  ["DOCUMENT_URI"]=> "/index.php/nextcloud/"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=> "/nextcloud/"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> "/index.php"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> "GET"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=> ""
  ["PATH_INFO"]=> "/nextcloud/"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> "//var/www/my.domain.net/public/index.php"```
I don't understand why :(

@LucaREz what's in fastcgi_params file?

the default file from nginx: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/fastcgi_params
another fun fact, if I ask for GET /nextcloud/index.php/login/ it answer me with the source code inside /var/www/nextcloud/public/index.php
